# Set VLAN ID to 0 in Linux

Tags: linux, vlan

I have an application, which send periodically TCP/IP packets from a master to a slave with Time Sensitive Networking, which is implemented inside tc-taprio in Linux. Every manual tells me that I need to create a new virtual Network Interface with some VLAN ID. But actually I
Is there a way to create a virtual Interface with a VLAN ID set to 0? Or not to set a VLAN ID at all?
English wikipedia describes the VLAN ID 0 with: VLAN not set.

Comment: Please see [THIS](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/24406) answer

Answer (score 0):

VLAN IDs 0x000 and 0xfff (0 and 4095) are reserved and cannot be used. Many implementations use VLID 0 for 'untagged'.